# Implementation of CHAP on android client/server

Tags: android, authentication, client-server

I'm trying to mimic CHAP to authenticate a user but somehow my hashes are always different on the server side(the one generated by client and the one s-generated by server). My code is as follows:

Server side

```
 public String getMD5Hex(String inputString) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
    md.update(inputString.getBytes());

    byte[] digest = md.digest();

    return digest.toString();
}

public Boolean aliceChapAuth(Socket socket, byte[] sharedKey) {

    Boolean check = false;

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        //generate challenge
        BigInteger b = new BigInteger(256, new Random());

        //send Challenge
        out.writeObject(b);
        out.flush();

        //receive hash
        String hash = (String)in.readObject();

        //compare foreign and local hash
        String s = sharedKey.toString();

        toastDisplay(getMD5Hex(b+s)+" "+hash);

        if(hash == getMD5Hex(b+s)) {

            check = true;
        }
        //send response


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return check;
}
```

N.B toastDisplay() is just a method I use to toast my strings

```
 public void bobChapAuth(Socket socket, byte[] sharedKey) {

    try {
        ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
        ObjectInputStream in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

        //receive challenge
        BigInteger b = (BigInteger)in.readObject();

        //String s = new String(sharedKey);
        String s = sharedKey.toString();
        //byte[] bytes = example.getBytes();

        //Hash the challenge+sharedSecret
        String hash = getMD5Hex(b+s);

        //send the hash
        out.writeObject(hash);
        out.flush();

        toastDisplay(hash);

        //get final response

    } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

The hash sent from the client is received successfully and is the same.

Comment: `(b+s)` Adding a BigInteger and a String. What would be the result?

Comment: im trying to concatenate the two

Comment: `byte[] sharedKey ) String s = sharedKey.toString();`. You will get a java identifier for the array. Has nothing to do with the content of the array. And will be different for server and client.

Comment: How would you concatenate a BigInteger and a String? What would be the result? Please explain what you do. And tell the result! Give an example! And what sense does it make trying to concatenate them? Please explain.

Comment: From my understanding of chap, server sends challenge(random characters); Client responds with the hash of the challenge and shared secret; then the server authenticates the client after performing the same operation and comparing the its result with the received one.

Comment: Fine. But you did not explain why your approach would work. And you did not answer my specific questions.

Comment: I had not paid much attention on the concatenation part, but after a lil googling I learnt that the bigInt will ba converted to string then concatenated with the other string just as two normal strings.

Comment: I think i have found the major problem, thanks to you, String s = sharedKey.toString(); and if(hash == getMD5Hex(b+s)) were the culprits. thanks again...

But were you implying that my approach is wrong? Please shed more light if you can.